# 特定のPCでのみコンテンツが開ける暗号化機能付USBはありますか？

Tags: usb

特定のPCでのみコンテンツが開ける暗号化機能付USBは存在するのでしょうか？

USBに配布する機密データを入れ、特定の許可されたユーザーだけが閲覧できるようにするのがゴールです。なお、そのUSBから情報をPCにコピーすることができないユースケースと考えています。必要な時にそのUSBを差してファイルを参照するが、PCにはUSB内の情報は残らない。万が一、USBをなくしても、その特定のPC（ユーザー）でしか開けない運用をイメージしています。

これに近い方法でも結構です。何かアイディアがあれば、ご共有いただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `特定のPC` を判別する方法にもよりますが、開くのを困難にするまでは可能でも不可能にしたり悪意を持ったユーザーが別のPCにコピーするのを防ぐのは難しそうです。

Comment: 想定するOSなどありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 Pro(またはそれ以上のエディション)前提で話をします。

BitLockerで鍵をパスワードでは無くファイル(または資格情報)にして、その鍵ファイルがあるPCでしか開けないと言うことはできそうです。しかし、鍵ファイルがコピーされたら終わりですし、USBからファイルを取り出せないといった制限を行うことはできません。

ファイルを取り出せないなどの制限を掛けたいのであれば、もっと総合的な暗号化ソフトを用いる必要があると思います。私が知っている製品でできそうなのは日立ソリューションズの秘文シリーズと富士通ビー・エス・シーのFENCEシリーズです。これらの製品については、ここで聞くより、日立系や富士通系の営業に相談した方が早いと思います。

Answer (score 0):

一応それらしい製品は見たことはありますが、その場ではメーカー名の公表も避けるようにガイドされていたので案内出来ません。

製品で行うのであればIBM、東芝、NEC、富士通辺りのHWにも強いIT企業の営業に問い合わせたほうがいいでしょう。

アプリを自作するのであれば、PC側は内蔵機器とUSBドライブを含む接続機器のデバイスIDやシリアルといったHW情報、
N/W機器のmacアドレス、ソフトウエアのライセンスキー情報等を全て取得して長大な判定用キーを作成し、
ドライブ全体を暗号化したUSBドライブとPC側に一部を分割して保持させる。
LAN上にセキュリティサーバを用意して正当なアクセスかを判定して残りのキーを返す。
復号化のキーも判定用キーを含ませて同様にUSBドライブとPC、セキュリティサーバに分割して保管といったところでしょうか。

ここまでやると故障とかでPCのパーツ交換するだけで復号化できなくなりますが。

Answer (score 0):

※点数が足りないのでコメント･返信できないようなのでここでお礼を記しておきます。

@PicoSushi
ありがとうございました。確かに悪意をもっているユーザーへの対応には限界がありますね。

@sayuri
ありがとうございます。OSはWin10がメインです。Win8以前のものはCD+Discloneを使って配布しています。

@らっしー
BitLockerの鍵ファイルをクライアントPCに入れていただいて、運用するかたちもたしかに楽で魅力的なのですが、仰る通り、鍵ファイル自体がコピーされない保証はないのがないのも、ファイルを取り出せなくすることもできないのはネックですね（ファイルを取り出せても、他のPCで開けなければ問題ありませんが…）。
富士通のFENCEは知っていましたが、日立の秘文シリーズは知りませんでした。情報をありがとうございます。確認してみます。

@通りすがり
IBM、東芝、NEC、富士通など、いずれもセキュリティーソリューションを出していますが、どこも結構大がかりなもので、コストも高すぎたりします。今回対象としているのは、オフラインでしかコンテンツを使えないユーザー様への製品関連ドキュメント一式の配布で、年に数回程度しか行わないものです。こうした背景もあり、できるだけ小規模に導入できるソリューションを考える必要があるのです。とは言え、自作というのは、考えていません（現在、うちで自作した証明書の仕組みを使っていますが、何もかも対応を自分たちでやらないといけないことや、対応できる人が限られていることがリスクとして感じています）。

Comment: 質問時とアカウントが２つに分かれてしまっているようです。質問者であれば信用度に関係なく自由にコメント等できますので、[こちらのヘルプページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)からアカウントを統合して頂き、再度ご投稿頂ければと思います。お手数ですがどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。